# Simple homotopy type of interval bundles over surfaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Consider  a locally  trivial (topological)  bundle  over the  Klein  bottle
$$ I\to E \to K$$
The  projection  map  $E \to K$ is  a  homotopy  equivalence.
 Is  it  a simple  homotopy  equivalence?
Due  to  the  dimension  of the  base (2),  one  cannot  use  Whitehead torsion to  check  simple  homotopy  equivalence.

Comment: Triangulate the bundle so that projection is simplicial. Inducting downwards, use that there is a way to push in simplices on $\Delta \times I$ to deformation retract this onto $\Delta \times {1/2} \cup \partial \Delta \times I$, where the {1/2} should be the 0 section.